# What are the differences between: $\sqrt{(-3)^2}$, $\sqrt{-3^2}$ and $(\sqrt{-3})^2$.

Tags: notation, radicals

First, is $\sqrt{-3}$ is equal to $-3$ or is it imaginary?

What is the difference between:

- $\sqrt{(-3)^2}$
- $\sqrt{-3^2}$
- $(\sqrt{-3})^2$

Can I write $(\sqrt{-3})^2  = -3$?

And, given the rule that $\sqrt{a^n}$ is equal to ($\sqrt{a})^n$, can I say that $\sqrt{-3^2}=-3$?

Comment: You should note that $-3^2 = -9 \neq (-3)^2 = 9$, since $-3^2$ is nothing different than $-1 \cdot 3^2$. Therefore $\sqrt{-3^2} = \sqrt{-9} = 3i$.

Comment: but in  $(\sqrt{-3})^2$  i can simplify the exponent '2' with the square root to  result -3 ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, since $\sqrt{x}$ is the inverse function of $x^2$. You should be aware though that in general, $\left(\sqrt{x^2}\right) = |x|$ has two solutions

Comment: Excuse me, I mean  $(\sqrt{-3})^2$ . Can this be simplified to -3 ?

Comment: I edited my comment :)

Comment: ok but if I can say that $\sqrt{a^n}$ is equal to $(\sqrt{a})^n$, I can say that $\sqrt{-3^2}$ is equal to $(\sqrt{-3})^2$ ?
So, i can say that $\sqrt{-3^2}$ is equal to -3 ?

Comment: As Antonio.G stated in his answer, that rule only holds for positive numbers ($a > 0$). Besides that, if you were to use that rule for -3, you would have to put brackets around your -3. If you say $a = -3$, then $a^2 = (-3)^2$, not $-3^2$.

Comment: hummm. ok . thank you very much!

Comment: $-3^2 = -(3^2) = -9$ so $\sqrt {-3^2} $ is imaginary.  By convention $\sqrt $ is defined to be the positive of two square roots.  So $\sqrt {a^2} = |a|$ (**assuming** a is real!!)  rather than $a $ in general.  But $a^2$ does have two square roots both a and -a.  Sometimes, but usually not, $\sqrt $ can mean both roots or either.  But usually it just refers to the positive one.

Answer (score 3):

The differences are in the order of operations. Parentheses are used to override the default order of operations.

Now, $\sqrt{-3}$ is most definitely NOT equal to $-3$. If $n$ is a positive integer, then $\sqrt{-n} = i \sqrt{n}$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ so that $i^2  = -1$. Then, since $\sqrt{3} \approx 1.732$, then $\sqrt{-3} \approx 1.732i$. On the real number line, center your compass on $0$ and put the pencil on $1.732$. Then, keeping the compass centered on $0$, move the pencil $90$ degrees.

And then:

- $\sqrt{(-3)^2} = 3$. Because of the parentheses, the first thing we do is multiply $-3$ by itself, giving us $(-3) \times (-3) = 9$, and $\sqrt{9} = 3$.
- $\sqrt{-3^2} = 3i$. Without the parentheses, we multiply $3$ by itself first (exponentiation has higher precedence than negation), giving us $9$, and then we multiply it by $-1$, so at this point we have $\sqrt{-9}$, which is $3i$.
- $(\sqrt{-3})^2 = -3$. Here the parentheses mean that we multiply $\sqrt{-3}$ by itself, and that gives us $-3$.

Lastly, if I were you, I would put that "rule" about $\sqrt{a^n}$ out of my mind, before it leads me astray any further.

Comment: More generally, for real numbers $a$ and $b$ the equality $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ fails precisely when both are negative.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$,

$\sqrt{-3^2}=\sqrt{-9}=3i$,

$(\sqrt{-3})^2=(\sqrt{3}i)^2=-3$

The rule is true only in the case $a>0$.

Comment: When $n$ is odd, the rule is true for non-positive $a$s as well!

Comment: @Majid I don't think so: $\sqrt{(-1)^3}=\sqrt{-1}=i$; $\sqrt{-1}^3=i^3=-i$. Perhaps you were thinking of $(a^n)^{1/n}=a$, but even then it's not true with the "standard" complex power function $a^b=\exp(b\log a)$ with a branch cut for $a$ at the negative reals, because in that case $a^{1/n}$ is complex for $a$ negative.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$,

$\sqrt{-3^2}=\sqrt{-9}=\pm 3i$,

$(\sqrt{-3})^2=(\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{3})^2=(\pm i\sqrt{3})^2=-3$,

$\sqrt{a^n}=(\sqrt{a})^n $ iff $ a\geq 0$,

Comment: $(\pm i3)^2 \neq -3$

Comment: Erik Joensson thank you for the correction

Comment: When solving $x^2=a$ one writes $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$ with $\pm$ in front. However the notation $\sqrt{a}$ by itself does not imply $\pm$ in front: it only refers to the *principal* square root. So $\sqrt{-9}=3i$ but not $-3i$. (And $\sqrt{a^n}=(\sqrt{a})^n$ is not *equivalent* to $a\ge0$; equality may still hold when $a<0$ if $n$ is odd.)

Comment: if $a\geq 0$ then $\sqrt{a^n}=(\sqrt{a})^n$

if $a=-b< 0$ and  $n$ even then
$\sqrt{a^n}=\sqrt{(-b)^n}=\sqrt{b^n}=(\sqrt{b})^n=(\sqrt{-a})^n$

if $a=-b< 0$ and  $n$ odd then
$\sqrt{a^n}=\sqrt{(-1)^n(b)^n}=\sqrt{(-1)b^n}=(\sqrt{-1}(\sqrt{b})^n=\pm
i(\sqrt{-a})^n$